# PCI scan shows unknown vulnerabilities

Tags: vulnerability, pci-dss

Basit Submit Module Cross Site Scripting Vulnerability

DCP-Portal Cross Site Scripting Bugs, CVE-2004-2511 CVE- 2003-1536 CVE-2004-2512

These two vulnerabilities have been identified in the scan done against our website by a 3rd party reviewer. I'm unable to resolve these issues. Can anyone shed some light on these and how to resolve them?

Comment: 1st https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2004-2511 2nd https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2003-1536 3rd https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2004-2512 . Found some information on each of these, it also contains additional resources.

Comment: @AlexProbert Thanks for the information, sir but I've already gone through much more information regarding both Basit submit module and DCP-Portal. I'm not able to find a clear solution to mitigate the issue. I don't even know how these two are working as I'm not aware of their presence on the server. My server is Apache (Ubuntu) with wordpress installed. Also, do you know any alternatives to DCP-portal or Basit?

Comment: I suppose the best option is to look at techniques to prevent XSS, such as tag stripping.

Comment: @AlexProbert Can you tell how can I implement it on my apache server?

Comment: So the tag stripping would be in the HTML and regarding the apache (I'm not too sure what version you're running) https://geekflare.com/http-header-implementation/ seems like a good place to start, looking at the HTTP Headers.

Comment: @AlexProbert Thank you for the information Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously mentioned in the comments of the question.

It will be best to look at the HTTP headers

I have included an answer to a previous question, which can be used to address these issues.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10369475/4962088

https://geekflare.com/http-header-implementation/

It is also worth looking at validation when creating a website/web application, which can be seen using the link below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1996141/4962088